# How to embed/integrate WordPress blog into my own web site?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, blogs

I have a WordPress blog account already (abc.wordpress.com). And I have my own web site: www.xyz.com

I would like to integrate my WordPress blog content into my own site. Hopefully something like blog.xyz.com or just replace the home page of xyz.com with abc.wordpress.com

I know that I can download WordPress' code from wordpress.org and run my own WordPress. And having my own MySQL database, but WordPress is always releasing new code. I don't have the time to keep updating the source on my end to match it.

I'm running my own site as a hobby, so I prefer to let WordPress.com to manage the content for me and continue reuse my own blog at abc.wordpress.com, but make the content show up in my own site: xyz.com

I hope I was clear when explaining this.

Anyone knows a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please ask this question on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your main worry is about the updates, I would say don't be. A simple click of the 'Updates' button in the wordpress admin is all you need to do in order to apply the updates for wordpress. A notification will pop up alerting you of any updates.

And as Calle has already mentioned, you can retrieve your content via RSS, or you could just export your current content from Wordpress.com, import the content into your own site, and manage it there. Everything would be in one spot.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks. My main concern is more about how some major versions of the update can be also changing the MySQL database structures. I have seen that happening. If I host it on my own, then I will have to spend time on these. I just want to focus on writing.

I don't write blog often, but I will definitely want to use it sometimes to keep a record of my writing periodically as more like a notebook for my writing/thoughts.

I'm OK with programming. 

How difficult is it to move my stuff under abc.wordpress.com to my own MySQL database?

Comment: Not hard at all, once wordpress is installed on your own site, simply 'Import' your content that you have 'Exported' from abc.wordpress.com and it will do it all for you. Content, comments, everything.

Comment: Getting the information off of your blog using RSS and caching it is enough. You don't need to migrate your data from the blog into your own mySQL database - except if you install Wordpress there of course in which case you could use the export/import tools in the Wordpress admin interface. Wordpress updates will never screw with your tables in a way that will hurt you, that's a promise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how good you are with programming but there's a PHP library called Simple Pie which would help you retrieve your content via RSS (which Wordpress automatically generates for you). The adress is here: http://simplepie.org/

If you are not very good with programming, perhaps you can get someone to do it for you or find a script which is already written somewhere. I do think RSS is definitely the best way to go.

I also think you exaggerate the problems of hosting Wordpress yourself. It's not something that you have to keep updated with, and if you want to, all you have to do is log in from time to time, perhaps once a month (how often are you writing articles?), and click "update" and Wordpress will do everything for you. Both for your plugins and WP version.

Answer (score 0):

For the ability to use your own domain (xyz.com) and have wordpress redirect users from abc.wordpress.com(your wordpress blog) to your domain requires a premium account.

If you have a premium account then you can just log in to wordpress.com, click 'upgrades' and select 'domains'. From there you will see the option "Map an Existing Domain" and you will want to enter your domain here. Now your wordpress.com blog is what will show when users enter your domain's url (xyz.com).

Alternatively, if you need a workaround with a free wordpress.com account then you want to just embed your blog and for that you will need to use an RSS feed. Note: this method will not maintain your wordpress styles it will merely transport the content. Also by default not all browsers support RSS feeds.

You can view your blog's current feed by adding 'feed' to the end of your wordpress.com url, i.e. abc.wordpress.com/feed. You can read more about feeds here (http://en.support.wordpress.com/feeds/). Now you are just left with the task of figuring out how to embed the feed into your page.

One final hail-mary you might attempt is just redirecting your domain to your blog. Reference on how to do this different ways here: (http://css-tricks.com/redirect-web-page/). Example, place this  tag in the  section of your domains pages:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='http://google.com'" />
```

(this will redirect after 0 seconds to the specified url)